# add colorFactor palette to mapview object

Tags: r, leaflet, mapview

The aim is to provide fixed colors to factor values. I struggle applying a colorFactor scale to a mapview object. However, the palette does not seem to match zcol.

I tried the following, similar to a leaflet map.

```
library(mapview)

colors <- colorFactor(palette = c("Red", "Green", "Blue"),
                      levels = c("Oberfranken","Mittelfranken", "Unterfranken"))

mapview(franconia, zcol = "district",col.regions=colors)
```

[image: Mapview Output]

I get the following error-message:

```
1: In col.regions(nregions) :   Some values were outside the color
scale and will be treated as NA
```

Any help on that?

the following would work on leaflet, but does not make use of mapview.

```
franconia %>% leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons(fillColor = ~colors(district))
```

[image: leaflet output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mapview::mapviewColors seems to do the trick:

```
library(mapview)

colors <- mapviewColors(x=franconia,
                        zcol = "district", 
                        colors = c("Red", "Green", "Blue"),
                        at = c("Oberfranken","Mittelfranken", "Unterfranken"))

mapview(franconia, zcol = "district",col.regions = colors)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't figure out how to use Beni's answer to specify which colour I wanted to apply to specific features on the map.

Turns out that `colorFactor` returns a function. You need to supply the field you want to use to colour the features:

```
library('sf')
library('leaflet')
library('mapview')
# Read in shapefile and keep the first three features
ncShp <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))[1:3, ]
ncShp
# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 14 fields
# Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -81.74107 ymin: 36.23388 xmax: -80.43531 ymax: 36.58965
# Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
# AREA PERIMETER CNTY_ CNTY_ID      NAME  FIPS FIPSNO CRESS_ID BIR74 SID74 NWBIR74 BIR79 SID79 NWBIR79                       geometry
# 1 0.114     1.442  1825    1825      Ashe 37009  37009        5  1091     1      10  1364     0      19 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.47276 3...
# 2 0.061     1.231  1827    1827 Alleghany 37005  37005        3   487     0      10   542     3      12 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.23989 3...
# 3 0.143     1.630  1828    1828     Surry 37171  37171       86  3188     5     208  3616     6     260 MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.45634 3...

cols <- c('red', 'green', 'blue')

# Colour our features sequentially based on the NAME field
ncShp$NAME
# [1] "Ashe"      "Alleghany" "Surry" 
# Ashe will be red, Alleghany will be green, Surry will be blue

colPal <- leaflet::colorFactor(palette = cols, levels = ncShp$NAME)
# Note: use levels(ncShp$NAME) if it's already a factor

# Send it to mapview
mapview::mapview(ncShp, zcol='NAME', col.regions=colPal(ncShp$NAME))
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, thats helpful! The corresponding mapview solution would be: 
`colPal <- mapview::mapviewColors(x = ncShp, zcol= "NAME", colors = cols, at = ncShp$NAME)

mapview::mapview(ncShp, zcol='NAME', col.regions=colPal)`

I don't know which one would be better for which case. In this example, they both yield identical maps.

Comment: Yep, that works. And yep, I don't know what the difference between the two is.